# What is the difference between 网上 and 在线?

Tags: meaning

Both 网上 and 在线 mean "online".
What is the difference between 网上 and 在线?

Comment: more examples at bkrs:  **网上**  on the net,#2255， 网上邻居,放到网上,在网上流传,网上年度报告,他成天在网上, many more, **在线**  comp. online #17378,在线采访,在线预订,在线翻译,在线出版物,在线数据输入,在线商务信息, many more

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specifically, although “网上” and “在线” can be both translated as "oline", “网上” actually means "on the internet", “在线” means "online".

Here are some examples

> 我在网上找到了这篇文章。

It means, I found this article **online**.

> 我的 QQ 是在线的。

This means, the status of my QQ is **online**.

Although they were both translated to "online", I bet you can see the difference there with actual examples.

Answer (score 2):

在线 is more for instant messenger like facebook/whatsapp status that you are online.

网上 is for website elements, for example, an online forum, online application.